# How to run PHP file in github page website?

Tags: php, html, web, github-pages

So i was adding a **.php** file to my **github website** with an email sender form, but when i try running it on my website it makes me **download it instead of making it run directly in the browser**. I was also trying to research something and i saw something about **apache**, but i don't know how to do it and how it works.

What i tried is to change the extension to **.html** but unfortunately, it sended me a **405 error "not allowed"**.
I'm sure the code is right and the only thing is that it dosn't make me run it.

What i want is that the php file, runs on the browser instead of making me download it.

Comment: You need to (1) install PHP and (2) set apache (or nginx or similar) to use PHP to interpret PHP files

Comment: But i don't know how to do it.

Comment: google on installation of LAMP or XAMPP and there are many tutorials telling you to set up such an environment

Comment: Is there another way to run it in browser because i don't want it to run into a software, i expected something like a special code like .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by **GitHub Website** you mean **[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)**...

**You can't.**

GitHub websites are mostly static - you, as a developer, push html or markdown and github provides/generates static content for viewers/browsers.

If you want to have a PHP-based backend, you need to use a different service. Alternatively, if your PHP code can generate static html, you can run it in a github action and push the html into github pages - but once done, it will stay as is until the next run.

Edit: also check [the video on their site](https://youtu.be/2MsN8gpT6jY), which among other things, says:

> There are no databases to set up or servers to configure